# update query and calculation part in GRN

Tags: mysql, netbeans

```
 String status = "active", nit = "", grniid = "", sumn = "";

            try {
                Connection ss = Class_DB.myconnection();
                Statement st = ss.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select stock_in_hand from item_supplier where item_ID =('" + TF_GRN_ITEMID.getSelectedItem() + "')");
                grniid = TF_GRN_NO_OF_ITEM.getText();
                int aa = Integer.parseInt(grniid);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    nit = rs.getString("stock_in_hand");
                }
                int bb = Integer.parseInt(nit);
                sumn = grniid + nit;
                int cc = Integer.parseInt(sumn);

                st.executeUpdate("insert into grn1 values('" + TF_GRN_GRNNO.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_SUPPLIERID.getSelectedItem() + "','" + TF_GRN_AMOUNT.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_DATE.getText() + "')");
                st.executeUpdate("insert into grn2 values('" + TF_GRN_GRNNO.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_ITEMID.getSelectedItem() + "','" + TF_GRN_EXP_DATE.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_TAX.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_NO_OF_ITEM.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_GAMOUNT.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_NAMOUNT.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_QTY.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_UNIT.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_FREE.getText() + "','" + TF_GRN_DIS.getText() + "')");
                st.executeUpdate("update item_supplier set stock_in_hand='" + cc + "' where item_ID='" + TF_GRN_ITEMID.getSelectedItem() + "'");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");
                clearing();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is some error.Please contact admin");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is the `GRN Query`. GRN stands for Good Receive Note. 
When we recieve Goods/Items from the supplier the company receives a GRN.
The Details of the items will be included in the GRN.
These data/details will be inserted in `GRN1` table, `GRN2` table and `item_Supplier` table will be updated according to it.

- `nit` is the variable, using `item_id` table and `item supplier` table, stock in hand will be retrieved.
- `bb` is the variable used to pass `nit` to an integer.
- `grnid` is No of items which we type in the interface will be included in `grnid`variable.
- `aa` is the variable used to pass grnid to integer.
- `class_DB` - connection class of the database.

Our problem is

1) he is inserted to `GRN1` and `GRN2` tables, but `item_supplier` table is not updated.

2) We want to know if our calculation is correct or not.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of ambiguity in this code between string and integer types. That sumn = grniid + nit is suspect. As are the sql statements, where you quote every value... even those that I would expect to be numeric. And then I see no transaction. You say it doesn't update the item_supplier table... do you get an exception or you just don't see the updated data in the table?

Comment: There is no exception and we don't see any updated data in the table as well.